# Does there exist an unbounded function $f$ such that for all $\mu_n$ converging to some probability measure $\sup_n \int f(z) \mu_n(dz) <\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Does there exist an unbounded positive function $f$ such that for all sequence of probability measures $\mu_n$ converging to some probability measure $$\sup_n \int f(z) \mu_n(dz) <\infty$$

Comment: Just to clarify, is the convergence of the $\mu_n$ convergence in measure?

Comment: Are the $\mu_n$ themselves probability measures?

Comment: If they are positive measures, just take $f$ to be negative and unbounded below.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: yes they are probability measures. $f$ is a positive function.

Comment: If $f$ is positive and unbounded, you can find a probability measure $\mu$ such that $\int f(z)\mu(dz)=\infty$.  Then, the sequence $\mu_n$ where $\mu_n=\mu$ fails the desired property.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is positive and unbounded above, there is a probability measure $\mu$ such that $\int f(z) \; \mu(dz) = \infty$.  For example, take a sequence 
$z_k$ with $f(z_k) > 2^k$, and $\mu(\{z_k\}) = 2^{-k}$ for $k = 1,2, \ldots$.  If $\mu_n \to \mu$ in any sense that implies $\mu_n(\{z_k\}) \to \mu(\{z_k\})$ for each $k$, then $\sup_n \int f(z)\; d\mu_n(z) = \infty$.